# matlab system identification toolbox gives me incorrect DC gain of transfer function

Tags: matlab, system-identification

everyone. I'm trying to build a noise model using system identification toolbox.

My system can be written as: **y = C(z)/D(z) e** . Basically I measure system response y purely due to unmeasured white noise **e** . I think system id will do the job since it's just an **ARMA** model.

Before applying it to real data, I wrote the following test script, which simulates a known system with whitenoise input and try to use the response y to get an estimated model and compare it with the known one by plotting their bode. **My problem is that** the estimated bode has the same shape as the true one, but the **DC gain is very different**. Can some one read my script and tell me what is wrong? THANK YOU!

```
close all; close all;
wn = 10;
sys = tf([wn^2], [1, 2*0.9*wn wn^2]);

% discretize;
Ts    = 0.025;
sysdt = c2d(sys, Ts);
Fs    = 1/Ts;
Tn    = 4;
N     = Tn/Ts;
Tsim = (0:N-1)' * Ts;

whitenoise = randn(N, 1);
Y          = lsim(sysdt, whitenoise, Tsim);

%the "input" u is 0, we have only noise e
td_data    = iddata(Y, zeros(size(Y)), Ts);

%% estimate use different commands
%1.armax model: A(q) y(t) = B(q) u(t-nk) +  C(q) e(t)
% syntax: M = armax(data,  [na, nb, nc, nk]
idout_armax = armax(td_data, [2, 0, 1, 1]);
idsys_armax = tf(idout_armax.c, idout_armax.a, Ts);
figure, bode(sysdt, idsys_armax)
legend('true model', 'armax')

%2. Box_Jenkins:  y(t) = [B(q)/F(q)] u(t-nk) +  [C(q)/D(q)]e(t)
%                      b+1 c  d  f  k
idout_bj = bj(td_data, [1, 1, 2, 1, 0]);
idsys_bj = tf(idout_bj.c, idout_bj.d, Ts);
figure, bode(sysdt, idsys_bj)
legend('true model', 'box jenkins')

%3. If I use the whitenoise data as input *u* , I can get correct DC gain with oe (most of the time).
td_data_wn = iddata(Y, whitenoise, Ts);
% OE model: y(t) = [B(q)/F(q)] u(t-nk) +  e(t)
%                         nb nf nk
idout_oe = oe(td_data_wn, [1, 2, 0]);
idsys_oe = tf(idout_oe.b, idout_oe.f, Ts);
figure, bode(sysdt, idsys_oe), legend('sysdt', 'idsys oe')
```

Answer (score 1):

I found out a possible reason for the DC gain by myself:

The system identification toolbox gives an estimation of the noise variance. So although I generate my data using randn with variance 1, the toolbox assumes (estimates) another noise variance, which I should use to scale my estimated transfer function to get the right DC gain.

So if in the above code, the armax model estimation part, I use

```
idout_armax = armax(td_data, [2, 0, 1, 1]);
scale = sqrt(idout_armax.NoiseVariance);
idsys_armax = tf(idout_armax.c, idout_armax.a, Ts)*scale;
figure, bode(sysdt, idsys_armax)
```

the DC gain should (almost) match sometimes.

I hope this is the correct reason.

Comment: is this question still valid?